# User inputs name, console shows name in textbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms

So I'm doing some homework here and I'm completely stuck. I'm a beginner in programming and preferably just a hint or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
What I'm supposed to do in this project is the following:

User puts in their first name in one text box.
User puts in their last name in the second text box.
The user clicks a button.
A textbox says; "Hello " + user1stname + " " + user2ndname

It's a very simple project but I just can't remember how to do it.
I'm mainly having trouble starting, I don't know where to start with this.
My thoughts on solving this:

I think I'm supposed to click the button, and string the first and last names, convert them and then they'll show up in the output.

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio and the project is Windows Form Application.

Comment: Use the accept answer button if he helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop `two textboxes` and `one button` from your toolbox, and double click your button write this code into button click event:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Hello {0} {1}",textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. I was able to work on my own code, but your use of messagebox saved me. I didn't think about using the MessageBox, instead I just had 3 textboxes. Thanks for the help and good day. :)